# Function getting executed even without clicking?

Tags: javascript

I am making a web app using javaScript and in one part, a list is dynamically generated. I want to make each list item to be clickable and a function to execute.

Anyhow, I note that the function is executed automatically when the page is loaded, even without clicking and when I click on it later, nothing happens.

Here is the code:

```
window.onload=function loadData(){
var goalsStr = localStorage.getItem("goalsNames");
var goalsObj = JSON.parse(goalsStr);
if (goalsObj !== null)
for(var i=0; i<goalsObj.length; i++){
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    node.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    node.setAttribute("id","i");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(goalsObj[i]);
    node.appendChild(textnode);                 
    node.addEventListener('click', viewGoal(goalsObj[i]), false);
    document.getElementById("sortable").appendChild(node);  
    }
} 
function viewGoal(goal){
alert("this should not happen");
}
```

I even tried using .setAttribute('onclick', method, but that too is not working. What's wrong? What should I do?

Comment: Why, you're calling the function of course. Put it in quotes and concat that variable or wrap it in an anonymous function.

Comment: @Jeremy But now, I am not able to pass the argument. What should I do?

Comment: Remember? I said to concat the variable. I do suggest wrapping it in an anonymous function, though.

Comment: @Jeremy I am able to send constant values, and constant variables but not variables whose value change during the execution of fox loop. I tried global variables, storing value in a temp variable but nothing worked. I have even tried goalsObj[i] + ' ' as the argument (i.e., concat) but still no use.

Comment: @Jeremy What kind of syntax do you mean by concat?

Comment: `node.addEventListener('click', 'viewGoal('+goalsObj[i]+')', false);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're adding the event listener, you need to pass in a function, meaning, don't include the `()` -- else it will execute immediately!

```
node.addEventListener('click', function() {
    viewGoal(goalsObj[i])
}, false);
```

Comment: But now, I am not able to pass the argument. What should I do?

Comment: The argument is passed in just fine above

Comment: @When I try to use the passed argument in the called function, it becomes "undefined" instead of the actual value.

Comment: Probably need a closure.

Comment: What does closure means?

Comment: I am able to send constant values, and constant variables but not variables whose value change during the execution of fox loop. I tried global variables, storing value in a temp variable but nothing worked. I have even tried goalsObj[i] + ' ' as the argument (i.e., concat) but still no use.